# How to check whether the value of my scope data is changed or not in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have created a html for customized dropdown.path of below html is "partials/institutions/coordinatorDropdown.html"

```
<div class="dropdown"  ng-click="toggleDropDown">
<button class="form-control overflow" type="button" id="dropdownMenu-list" data-toggle="dropdown" name="datatype" id="datatype" ng-required="true" ng-class="{ 'selected-class-name': $index == selectedIndex }" ng-model="coordinator.role" ng-bind="coordinator.role" required>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-list" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu-list"  ng-init="toggleDropDown = true" ng-show="toggleDropDown" >
    <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="item in role" value="{{ item.roleid }}" ng-click="changeCoordinatorType(item.value, $index)">
        <span ng-class="{ 'dropdown-selected-item': $index == selectedIndex }">{{ item.coordinator_type }}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In my original html i am using this like below:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="error-message">
                    <span ng-show="addCoordinatorForm.coordinatorType.$error.required && !addCoordinatorForm.coordinatorType.$pristine"
                          class="errormessage" ng-bind="'Please select a coordinator type.'"></span>
                </div>
                <div name="coordinatorType" ng-include="'partials/institutions/coordinatorDropdown.html'"></div>
            </div>
```

Now in my controller,

I need to check whether the $scope.coordinator.role value is changed or not.

In my controller when i give

```
if ($scope.addCoordinatorForm.$dirty){
}
```

It is checking the other controls but not the dropdown value changed or not.

Can anyone suggest a solution for me please?.